# Canot resolve android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I tried to set compileSdkVersion in my project to 23 and also updated the below libraries:

- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`
- `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1`
- `com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1`

Since then I am getting error at importing `android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView`

Can anyone please tell me why is it so? Any change in the package of TintImageView? Kindly help.

I am using Studio Preview 2.0

Comment: why? have you seen `internal` in the package name?

Comment: I didn't understand. What does 'internal' mean?

Comment: It was working fine when the compile SDK version was 22.

Comment: Are you getting this error in layout editor ?

Comment: No. In the Java file.

Comment: it, more or less, means you cannot use `TintImageView` directly in your code since it is `internal` class (hidden from devs usage)

Comment: try running this in terminal under the terminal panel in AS2.0 :  ./gradlew clean build

Comment: @pskink: Does that mean that I shouldn't use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It happens **because the class**

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView
```

**doesn't exist in the appcompat v 23.x.x**.

In general don't use the classes in the `internal` package.

You can check the source in the folder `androidsdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\`.

You should switch to the [`AppCompatImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html).

> A ImageView which supports compatible features on older version of the platform, including:
>
> - Allows dynamic tint of it background via the background tint methods in ViewCompat.
> - Allows setting of the background tint using backgroundTint and backgroundTintMode.
>
> This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for tinting an `ImageView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:tint="#636363"
    />
```